# Estimate JS function execution time

Tags: javascript, minimax

I have a very performance heavy function (minimax chess) and i want to get the approximate execution time without needing to run the function.

My function has different Levels.

I already have a function that calculates the time, but it just runs the minimax function and stops the time, which takes quite long.

I already stopped the time for 7 Levels but i want to get even higher.

Level 1: Usually about 100ms
Level 2: Usually about 400ms
Level 3: Usually about 3100ms (3,1 sec)
Level 4: Usually about 36500ms (36,5 sec)
Level 5: Usually about 305600ms (ca. 5,1 min)
Level 6: Usually about 1970981ms (ca. 32,8 min)
Level 7: Usually about 13855774ms (ca. 230,9 min or 3,8 hours)

As you can see they run longer and longer. If i run my time stopping function for level 8 it would run pretty long and i don`t have all that time to wait.

Any help is appreciated!

If something is unclear don`t hesitate to ask me.

#### Also, if you see a (mathematical) pattern in my already made measurements, that would allow to calculate the next, this would solve my Problem aswell!

#### This is my JS WebWorker, that will run the function:

#### To run the function you just do `makeAIMove(yourlevelhere);`.

```
self.importScripts("workerFakeDOM.js");

self.importScripts('jquery.js');
self.importScripts('../js/chessboard-0.3.0.min.js');
self.importScripts('../js/chess.js');

var game, positionCount;

self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    game = new Chess();
    game.load(e.data.fen);
    //console.log(e);
    move = makeAIMove(e.data.root);
    self.postMessage(move);
}, false);

function makeAIMove(root) {
    var start = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    r = minimaxRoot(root, game, true);
    console.log(r);
    var stop = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    $("#ai").html("This looks good to me... I was thinking for " + Math.floor(stop - start) + " Seconds...");
    return r;
}

var minimaxRoot =function(depth, game, isMaximisingPlayer) {

    var newGameMoves = game.moves();
    var bestMove = -9999;
    var bestMoveFound;

    for(var i = 0; i < newGameMoves.length; i++) {
        var newGameMove = newGameMoves[i]
        game.move(newGameMove);
        var value = minimax(depth - 1, game, -10000, 10000, !isMaximisingPlayer);
        game.undo();
        if(value >= bestMove) {
            bestMove = value;
            bestMoveFound = newGameMove;
        }
    }
    return bestMoveFound;
};

var minimax = function (depth, game, alpha, beta, isMaximisingPlayer) {
    positionCount++;
    if (depth === 0) {
        return -evaluateBoard(game.board());
    }

    var newGameMoves = game.moves();

    if (isMaximisingPlayer) {
        var bestMove = -9999;
        for (var i = 0; i < newGameMoves.length; i++) {
            game.move(newGameMoves[i]);
            bestMove = Math.max(bestMove, minimax(depth - 1, game, alpha, beta, !isMaximisingPlayer));
            game.undo();
            alpha = Math.max(alpha, bestMove);
            if (beta <= alpha) {
                return bestMove;
            }
        }
        return bestMove;
    } else {
        var bestMove = 9999;
        for (var i = 0; i < newGameMoves.length; i++) {
            game.move(newGameMoves[i]);
            bestMove = Math.min(bestMove, minimax(depth - 1, game, alpha, beta, !isMaximisingPlayer));
            game.undo();
            beta = Math.min(beta, bestMove);
            if (beta <= alpha) {
                return bestMove;
            }
        }
        return bestMove;
    }
};

var evaluateBoard = function (board) {
    var totalEvaluation = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            totalEvaluation = totalEvaluation + getPieceValue(board[i][j], i ,j);
        }
    }
    return totalEvaluation;
};

var reverseArray = function(array) {
    return array.slice().reverse();
};

var pawnEvalWhite =
    [
        [0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0],
        [5.0,  5.0,  5.0,  5.0,  5.0,  5.0,  5.0,  5.0],
        [1.0,  1.0,  2.0,  3.0,  3.0,  2.0,  1.0,  1.0],
        [0.5,  0.5,  1.0,  2.5,  2.5,  1.0,  0.5,  0.5],
        [0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  2.0,  2.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0],
        [0.5, -0.5, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0, -0.5,  0.5],
        [0.5,  1.0, 1.0,  -2.0, -2.0,  1.0,  1.0,  0.5],
        [0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0]
    ];

var pawnEvalBlack = reverseArray(pawnEvalWhite);

var knightEval =
    [
        [-5.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -5.0],
        [-4.0, -2.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, -2.0, -4.0],
        [-3.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.5,  1.5,  1.0,  0.0, -3.0],
        [-3.0,  0.5,  1.5,  2.0,  2.0,  1.5,  0.5, -3.0],
        [-3.0,  0.0,  1.5,  2.0,  2.0,  1.5,  0.0, -3.0],
        [-3.0,  0.5,  1.0,  1.5,  1.5,  1.0,  0.5, -3.0],
        [-4.0, -2.0,  0.0,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0, -2.0, -4.0],
        [-5.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -5.0]
    ];

var bishopEvalWhite = [
    [ -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0],
    [ -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0],
    [ -1.0,  0.0,  0.5,  1.0,  1.0,  0.5,  0.0, -1.0],
    [ -1.0,  0.5,  0.5,  1.0,  1.0,  0.5,  0.5, -1.0],
    [ -1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  0.0, -1.0],
    [ -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0, -1.0],
    [ -1.0,  0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.5, -1.0],
    [ -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0]
];

var bishopEvalBlack = reverseArray(bishopEvalWhite);

var rookEvalWhite = [
    [  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0],
    [  0.5,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  0.5],
    [ -0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, -0.5],
    [ -0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, -0.5],
    [ -0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, -0.5],
    [ -0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, -0.5],
    [ -0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, -0.5],
    [  0.0,   0.0, 0.0,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0]
];

var rookEvalBlack = reverseArray(rookEvalWhite);

var evalQueen =
    [
    [ -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -0.5, -0.5, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0],
    [ -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0],
    [ -1.0,  0.0,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0, -1.0],
    [ -0.5,  0.0,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0, -0.5],
    [  0.0,  0.0,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0, -0.5],
    [ -1.0,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0, -1.0],
    [ -1.0,  0.0,  0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0],
    [ -2.0, -1.0, -1.0, -0.5, -0.5, -1.0, -1.0, -2.0]
];

var kingEvalWhite = [

    [ -3.0, -4.0, -4.0, -5.0, -5.0, -4.0, -4.0, -3.0],
    [ -3.0, -4.0, -4.0, -5.0, -5.0, -4.0, -4.0, -3.0],
    [ -3.0, -4.0, -4.0, -5.0, -5.0, -4.0, -4.0, -3.0],
    [ -3.0, -4.0, -4.0, -5.0, -5.0, -4.0, -4.0, -3.0],
    [ -2.0, -3.0, -3.0, -4.0, -4.0, -3.0, -3.0, -2.0],
    [ -1.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0],
    [  2.0,  2.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  2.0,  2.0 ],
    [  2.0,  3.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  3.0,  2.0 ]
];

var kingEvalBlack = reverseArray(kingEvalWhite);



var getAbsoluteValue = function (piece, isWhite, x ,y) {
    if (piece.type === 'p') {
        return 10 + ( isWhite ? pawnEvalWhite[y][x] : pawnEvalBlack[y][x] );
    } else if (piece.type === 'r') {
        return 50 + ( isWhite ? rookEvalWhite[y][x] : rookEvalBlack[y][x] );
    } else if (piece.type === 'n') {
        return 30 + knightEval[y][x];
    } else if (piece.type === 'b') {
        return 30 + ( isWhite ? bishopEvalWhite[y][x] : bishopEvalBlack[y][x] );
    } else if (piece.type === 'q') {
        return 90 + evalQueen[y][x];
    } else if (piece.type === 'k') {
        return 900 + ( isWhite ? kingEvalWhite[y][x] : kingEvalBlack[y][x] );
    }
    throw "Unknown piece type: " + piece.type;
};

var getPieceValue = function (piece, x, y) {
    if (piece === null) {
        return 0;
    }

    var absoluteValue = getAbsoluteValue(piece, piece.color === 'w', x ,y);
    return piece.color === 'w' ? absoluteValue : -absoluteValue;
};
```

#### Further Explanation:

This whole thing is for a Chess AI written in JS.

The function `makeAIMove(root);` will return the best move.

`game.moves();` returns the possible moves at the moment.
`game.move(move);` will do the move `move`.
`e.data.fen` contains the [FEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) string of the current Game.
`game.load(fen);` will load a game with the [FEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) string `fen`
`$("#ai")` is a paragraph containing the ai's "voice"
`game.undo();` undoes the last move

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes, that is correct. But my way of checking will run the function. (and as noted this takes quite some time) I need a way to get the approximate execution time without needing to run the function.

Comment: if the ratio of work between level 1 and 5 is linear, you can time level 1 and scale accordingly.

Comment: maybe if we could see the function it would be possible to think of an estimation strategy

Comment: [Looks](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=[100,+400,+3100,+36500,+305600,+1970981]) roughly exponential.

Comment: @OvidiuDolha Yes, one second i will ad it